# ¿Cómo rastrear las páginas que visitan los usuarios en mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html5, web, aplicación-web, google-analytics

Quisiera rastrear las páginas que visitan los usuarios que entran en mi sitio web de manera independiente.

Por ejemplo:

```
Usuario1: inicio,acerca_de,visitanos;
Usuario2: acerca_de,inicio,visitanos;
```

He intentado con Google Analytics pero solo ofrece los datos ya procesados y a mi me interesa la información completa.

Comment: si tienes analitycs, lo puedes hacer con eso.. a traves de https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=es-419#modifying_page_urls